# Android: How to detect when location is turned on/off by user?

Tags: android, android-location

We could declare `<action android:name="android.location.PROVIDERS_CHANGED" />` broadcast in `Manifest` till Android Nougat. But since `Implicit Broadcast` does not work in **Android Oreo** (except a few), how else can we detect it on device running Oreo.

One solution is to register the broadcast at runtime but I want to detect it even when the app is not running.

I checked `JobScheduler` API but I couldn't find any trigger for Location toggle.

According to Android documentation

> The app must re-register geofences if they're still needed after the
> following events, since the system cannot recover the geofences in the
> following cases:
>
> The app has received a GEOFENCE_NOT_AVAILABLE alert. This typically
> happens after NLP (Android's Network Location Provider) is disabled.

Since all geofences need to be re-registered when location is turned back on, I want to detect this even when app is not running.

Comment: You can make service for check at specific interval and send status to server using you API.

Comment: @ChiragSavsani My problem is Android Oreo specific. And you can't run services freely in Android O. We can do this using JobScheduler though but checking at specific interval is not a good way as user might keep location turned off for days. I'm curious if Android has provided any alternative to it.